# Group/sort array by keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array like this:

```
"New York",
"Chicago",
"Los Angeles",
"Boston",
"New York",
"Miami",
"Houston",
"New York",
"Miami",
"Chicago",
...
```

What i want now is a) group the array by key, b) count the amount and c) sort it by amount.

After that the new array should look like this:

```
"New York" => 2,
"Miami" => 2,
"Chicago" => 2,
"Los Angeles" => 1,
"Boston" => 1,
"Houston" => 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `$count = array_count_values($arr);` <- And Done!

Answer (score 1):

Very easy.

Just use the following code:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Will output the following

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

See [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: And how can i sort the result by the numbers? Biggest amounts on top?

Comment: @WeekendCoder It is automatically sorted that way (BTW: Look at the possible duplicate, your question was already answered)

Comment: wow you just completely copied the example from the manual! Nobody can tell that this is a answer to this question, it also can be a PHP tutorial

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't see the point of writing another example when this one work perfectly fine. Also, the OP didn't show any work he did ("what have you done") so I only pointed him to the right direction.